# How to bind BindingList<T>.Count property to specific label text?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, bindinglist

I have some label that should display actual amount of items that contain BindingList that bound to the DataGridView.

I tried to bind in this way:

```
CountOfLoadedItemsLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", _items.Count, String.Empty);
```

But when BindingList updates, the label that bound to its Count property not changes.

Answer (score 0):

Never used BindingList<T> but this worked for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Test> list;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.list = new BindingList<Test>
        {
            new Test(1,"Entry"),
            new Test(2,"Another Entry")
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list,null);
        list.ListChanged += list_ListChanged;
        list.Add(new Test(3, "After Binding"));
    }

    void list_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CountOfLoadedItemsLabel.Text = string.Format("Items: {0}", list.Count);
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Test(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```